# C# need assistance with modifying datagridview real time

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to make the datagridview to be editable and real time. I got the stored procedure built into mysql and the following codes were suppose to load the procedure and run it. The issue is; there is no error, but the data is not being save at all. When I modify a cell, it would pop-up the successfully updated messagebox, but data is not being save. Any help is much appreciated.

```
    private void Gdata_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {


        if(Gdata.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        try 
        
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                DataGridViewRow GDataRow = Gdata.CurrentRow;
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SalesAddOrEdit", sqlCon); //load stored procedure

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                MessageBox.Show("Successfully updated!");

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_uid", Convert.ToInt32(GDataRow.Cells["txtUID"].Value));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_prodid", GDataRow.Cells["txtprodid"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtprodid"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_datepurchase", GDataRow.Cells["txtdate"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtdate"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_price", GDataRow.Cells["txtprice"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtprice"].Value.ToString());


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_customer_1", GDataRow.Cells["txtcus1"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtcus1"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_paid_1", GDataRow.Cells["txtpaid1"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtpaid1"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_shipped_1", GDataRow.Cells["txtship1"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtship1"].Value.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_customer_2", GDataRow.Cells["txtcus2"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtcus2"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_paid_2", GDataRow.Cells["txtpaid2"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtpaid2"].Value.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d_shipped_2", GDataRow.Cells["txtship2"].Value == DBNull.Value ? "" : GDataRow.Cells["txtship2"].Value.ToString());

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    sqlCon.Close();
                    //
                //Note for reader:
                //variables from procedure: d_(xxxx) example d_uid
                //column names(This is not the header) in datagridview: txt(xxxx) example: txtprice


                loaddata(); //once the cell updated, refresh the table to display the new changes.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"When I modify a cell, it would pop-up the successfully"* because there's a `try`/`catch` block and the code displays success before doing anything else. *"there is no error, but the data is not being save at all"* Then debug your code and check the value of the parameters. It is possible that some are empty and there's a `where` condition that returns no record for `update`.

Comment: I tried without the 'try' code before as well as removing the messagebox it's the same result. However are you saying that I should remove the where if cells are null then replace it with ""?

Comment: No, what I say is check that the filter returns records.

Comment: I found the issue. It has something to do with my procedure. Instead of declaring them, I had to put them inside the create procedure bracket like so:

CREATE PROCEDURE SalesAddOrEdit(d_uid int, d_prodid VARCHAR(255), d_price VARCHAR(255), d_customer_1 VARCHAR(255), d_paid_1 VARCHAR(255), d_shipped_1 VARCHAR(255), d_customer_2 VARCHAR(255), d_paid_2 VARCHAR(255), d_shipped_2 VARCHAR(255), d_customer_3 VARCHAR(255), d_paid_3 VARCHAR(255), d_shipped_3 VARCHAR(255)).

After removing the old procedure and updated the procedure; it finally updated as I expected.